# Progress DB casting a number to add a character

Tags: openedge, progress-db

I don't know how to describe this so I'm going to do my best here...

In a select:

```
SELECT "PUB"."EMPLOYEEID" as IdNum from Users
```

Works, and it pulls up a list of ID numbers.  However, I need the numbers to have a leading 0 if they are only 4 characters long.

So I wrote up a length checker and it was failing.  So I dropped back and just attempted to add a zero to all to see if that was causing the issue and sure enough it was.  It seems the column is a type number of some sort (I don't have access to the schema) so the command

```
SELECT '0' + "PUB"."EmployeeID" as IdNum from Users
```

Does not work...  I can add the '0' to a name field with no issues.  So I assume it's a casting issue of some sort.  With SQL Server I can do this without converting columns....  Unfortunately, I'm not extremely versed in Progress...

Comment: `SELECT [columnName] as [varName] from [Table]` means that `varName` is the column name. I'll comment again if I work out a solution

Answer (score 2):

You're correct it's a casting issue, as the column output must be formatted.

**Using SQL server**

Column `TEST` has type NUMERIC, with value `1115`

```
SELECT REPLICATE('0',5-LEN(RTRIM(TEST))) + RTRIM(TEST) AS TEST FROM STUDENT;
```

Outputs `01115`

The above code replicates a 0 for any value less than 5 characters in length.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That wasn't quite right...  But I did find the answer.

RIGHT('00000' + CONVERT('VARCHAR',"NAMEID"),5) as IDNum